# Is an argmax of products equal to a product of argmax's?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given that $f(x) \geq 0,g(y) \geq 0,h(z) \geq 0 \ \forall \ x,y,z$, is this statement true?

$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\argmax_{x,y,z} f(x) \cdot g(y) \cdot h(z) = \left[\argmax_{x} f(x)\right] \cdot \left[\argmax_{y} g(y)\right] \cdot \left[\argmax_{z} h(z)\right]
$$

**EDIT**

I am asking this question in the context of [belief propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_propagation) and the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm). Consider instead this true statement:

$$
\sum_{x,y,z} f(x) \cdot g(y) \cdot h(z) = \left[\sum_{x} f(x)\right] \cdot \left[\sum_{y} g(y)\right] \cdot \left[\sum_{z} h(z)\right]
$$

If I replace the summations with argmax's, is this statement still true?

Comment: Note that the LHS is a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, while the RHS is just a number in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think my notation may be off. I meant to say that the LHS is just a multiplication. Both of them are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get it. A multiplication of what?

Comment: I think the LHS means $x \cdot y \cdot z$, where $(x,y,z) = \operatorname{argmax} f(x) g(y) h(z)$

Comment: I have edited my question to better explain what I mean.

Comment: I think that you need to be a bit more specific on the definition of what you are looking for. On the one hand, note that $\argmax$ defines a set of points. On the other hand, the summation is an operator that reduces everything to a single value in $\R$, so the equality is well defined. But that is not the case of $\argmax$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true.  Let $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ denote the argmax on the right.  If you obtained anything else from the argmax on the left, say $(x',y^*,z^*)$, then replacing $x'$ with $x^*$ would only increase the LHS, never decrease it.

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what this means? Maybe provide an example?